# Is there a way to write statements after a #include other than comments?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out whether or not it is possible to write valid C++ code on the same line of a text editor. This isn't too tricky for the main function as everything is semi-colon delimited; however, haven't been able to figure out a way to write executable code after a `#include` statement.

I understand that the `#include` statements are part of pre-processing and therefore how they are handled is potentially compiler specific, so I went into the g++ documentation to look at how these statements are handled and was unable to find any answers. I've tried a semicolon, `\n`, `std::endl`, `/* */`, `,`, and pretty much everything I could think of without success.

My guess is that any solution would have to trick the compiler into thinking all the code after is on a newline, but I'm not sure whether or not this is possible. This is purely for sport, I understand that there is no necessity for such functionality and that it is horrible style.

Comment: No, with all my knowledge in code golfing.

Comment: pretty sure there is no such way. Which is unsurprising, since, as you pointed out yourself, it is unecessary and bad style, so why waste time on allowing the preprocessor to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

C++ translation is done (at least conceptually defined) in multiple phases. After the preprocessing phase, whitespace (including newlines) is no longer significant and the source code is just a stream of tokens. However, that only applies *after* preprocessing.

During the preprocessing phase, whitespace and newlines still matter. Most importantly, the C++ grammar effetively defines a preprocessor directive as:

*optional-whitespace* `#` *optional-preprocessor-keyword* *other-content* ***new-line***

So the newline is part of the grammar and cannot be skipped.

(Since this is defined in the standard, it is also not something subject to compiler-specific handling).

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible if you bypass the *preprocessor*, as once the preprocessor sees `#include` then the rest of that line is reserved for what you're including.

It is possible to submit a single line to the *compiler*. To do that you'll need to set up your toolchain to run *only* the preprocessor, massage that output to one line, and compile that.